# Bragging is bad for your reputation... but there is one exception: What is going on?

Tags: social-psychology

It might be that this question is not suitable for this SE site so feel free to close.

Several scientific studies prove what we all kind of know: That bragging is being frowned upon - see e.g. this article and the references within: [How to boast on the sly (The Atlantic, April 2016)](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2016/05/how-to-boast-on-the-sly/476373/)

Yet by now we all know one person who does basically nothing else but bragging, boasting, telling us that he is the most wonderful person on the planet... and let me hasten to add that seemingly people not only accept it but really embrace it and even seem to love it: Of course I am talking about Donald Trump!

**My question**
What is going on? What has the psychological literature to say about this seemingly paradox phenomenon?

Comment: I wouldn't claim Donald Trump has a 'good' reputation. Some people just fall for his antics, but not all. Psychology isn't about 'all or nothing'. From a political perspective, ["The rise of American authoritarianism"](http://www.vox.com/2016/3/1/11127424/trump-authoritarianism) will interest you.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Thank you, that is interesting.